# MaxHeight MaxWidth binding does not change UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm struggling with an issue where the following binding seems to have no impact on the UI:

```xml
<Toolbar MaxWidth="{Binding AllowedHorizontalSpace}" />
```

Property and field:

```
private int allowedHorizontalSpace;
public int AllowedHorizontalSpace {
    get { return this.allowedHorizontalSpace; }
    set { 
          this.allowedHorizontalSpace = value; 
          this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.AllowedHorizontalSpace));
        }
    }
```

In the function that listens for monitor size changes:

```
this.AllowedHorizontalSpace = (int) (monitorWidth * 0.4)
```

What am I missing? The size of the control just does not want to change! The same error persists for MaxHeight as well.

I have tried manually changing this value using the tool snoop. The change *is* reflected in the control when I do this.

Comment: Use a `DependencyProperty` instead of defining normal property. There is a snippet for it in vs. Just type `propdep` and press tab. Learn more here: [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Where (in which class) do you have the AllowedHorizontalSpace property defined? Your binding works on the DataContext. Does DataContext contain an object of the type declaring AllowedHorizontalSpace? (Just to be sure, also remember that WPF does not work with pixel units. If you get the monitor width in pixels, you would need to convert them to WPF units first.)

Comment: @elgonzo It is defined in the ViewModel. There are no binding errors in the output console, I am certain it is accessible and correctly bound.

Comment: What is the unit of monitorWidth? Pixels?

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, but I'm not sure why units would matter.

Comment: @Aryan would this solve the issue, or are you just suggesting an overall code improvement?

Comment: Because WPF uses 1/96 inch as unit. Without converting your pixel size to WPF units (1/96"), your MaxWidth might be set to a size much smaller than you expect. Not sure though, if this would align with the behavior you observe...

Comment: @elgonzo I don't think that's the issue. I can even set a custom value for this property in the debugger before INPC fires, and I still don't see any changes.

Comment: @Aryan Alright. Thanks for the suggestion, even though it doesn't solve the problem at hand. The property is being bound.

Comment: Hmm, whatever your problem, it can't be deduced from the code given in the question. One other reason i can think of right now is that in your code two objects with a AllowedHorizontalSpace property are instantiated somehow. While the binding is applied to one object, your code is altering the other object. But there could also be numerous other reasons of why your code does not behave as you expect. In short, i do not really have a clear and strong suspicion about what goes wrong there... :(

Comment: @Aryan It's a viewmodel property. The property is implemented correctly. It absolutely should not be a dependency property.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld If you can provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue, it should be solvable. Quite likely you'll find the problem while doing that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks, I wish I knew the exact reason..  Like you said, that'd solve it. I do have some more clues though

Comment: When I edit the property with Snoop, the setter AND the getter are both called, and the visual change occurs in the UI control. However, when I update the property by resizing my desktop, only the setter is called.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld Any chance of a duplicate viewmodel instance or something like that? What you describe would be consistent with the desktop-size-change event handler updating the wrong instance of the viewmodel: If that instance's property isn't the one that's bound, nothing's listening for changes, so nothing calls the getter in response to the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Hmmm. That's entirely possible. I noticed that the Initialize() method of my ViewModel is being called again on this event.

Comment: How do you recommend I solve this problem then? Is there some way to force it to resolve the original instance?

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld The way to make it use only one instance is to create only one instance. There's nothing mysterious about this: You created two of them, somehow. I can't confidently guess how because you won't show me any more code. If I had to place a bet, I'd guess you created one viewmodel instance in the codebehind constructor and another in XAML. If you put a breakpoint in the viewmodel constructor and look at the stack when it breaks into the debugger, you'll find out who's creating it.

Comment: I'm just astonished that you say "I noticed that the Initialize() method of my ViewModel is being called again on this event.", and then ask me how to fix it *without showing me a single line of code involved in any of what you just described*. I'm not psychic. How can I possibly guess what that Initialize() method does, or who calls it, or where or when that happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144668/discussion-between-ed-plunkett-and-alex-rosenfeld).

Comment: Thanks for the input and advice. As I mentioned previously, the amount of code I can share is *very* limited due to employer restrictions. I'm using internally developed frameworks to create and resolve the instance of the ViewModel, as well.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry, I thought it's a view property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, it comes out that when the monitor size changes, the setter for `AllowedHorizontalSpace` is called but not the getter.

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation looks right from here, and the whole thing works correctly when `AllowedHorizontalSpace` is set via Snoop, so it *is* right, and the `DataContext` must be an instance of your viewmodel.

This kind of thing is commonly caused by there being a redundant viewmodel instance. Often, one is created in the XAML, and another is created in the codebehind constructor. The second instance assigned to `DataContext` is the one the property will be bound to, but you may be setting the property on the first. In that case the setter would execute on the first, but since no bindings are using that instance as a source, nothing would call the getter.

And you mention that the viewmodel's `Initialize()` method is unexpectedly being called twice, which is what I'd expect if the above were the case.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that AllowedHorizontalSpace is not a dependency property yet you are using the dependency property change notification.

The thing to do is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the view model.  Change the property implementation to the following and everything will start working.

```
public int AllowedHorizontalSpace
{
    get { return this.allowedHorizontalSpace; }
    set
    {
        this.allowedHorizontalSpace = value;
        //                this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.AllowedHorizontalSpace));
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AllowedHorizontalSpace"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I return to work tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: That looks exactly like an ordinary INPC property, and nothing like a dependency property. There is no explicit change notification for dependency properties. Call SetValue and it does its thing.

Comment: I see why you may think this is the problem, however upon further review, your code and my code is the same. The method I use` OnPropertyChanged` performs the same .Invoke as your code.